# script tag inject but not execute on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

this script is created and injected correctly but not execute when try to instance it, but rightly works from browser console.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.id = 'mp';
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://sdk.mercadopago.com/js/v2';
  document.body.appendChild(script);

  const mp = new window.MercadoPago('PUBLIC-KEY', {
    locale: 'es-AR'
  });

  mp.checkout({
    preference: {
      id: '489283197-ac01a776-5696-46ff-a300-98853bd3472d'
    },
    render: {
      container: '.mp-test',
      label: 'Pagar',
    }
  });
}, [])
```

ERROR: window.MercadoPago is not constructor
[capture error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xOuY.png)

I hope suggestes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are 90% right on your code. The problem is that you are trying to use the script before it's finished downloading. On a side note, remember to remove the the script from the page when you leave (unmount) the component.

```js
const [mercadoPagoLoaded, setMercadoPagoLoaded] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement('script')
  script.src = 'https://sdk.mercadopago.com/js/v2'
  script.async = true // since it's an external resource, you need to execute it after it's downloaded.
  script.onload = () => {
    // Execute library related code after it has been loaded
    const publicKey = process.env.REACT_APP_MERCADOPAGO_PUBLIC_KEY
    window.MercadoPago = new window.MercadoPago(publicKey)
    window.MercadoPago.key = publicKey
    setMercadoPagoLoaded(true) // If you have dependencies, set its state as loaded.
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script)
  return () => {
    document.body.removeChild(script)
    delete window.MercadoPago
  }
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  if (mercadoPagoLoaded) {
    // ... Code dependent on the Library
  }
}, [mercadoPagoLoaded])
```